# Login Failing in Virtual Console

Tags: login, password, virtual-console

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

When hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>F2</kbd> ...) I get a terminal login prompt in the virtual console. After entering the user name and pressing enter, it shows the
Password: 
and immediately switches the cursor to the next line after Password. If I enter text there it shows it in cleartext (= not hidden). It does not accept a password and shows login failed after a short time out or after hitting enter again. It is as if the "Return" after the username is registered as two "Return" entries, skipping over the Password field immediately.

What could cause this or how can it be fixed?

I can login in the GUI and also via ssh with these user names (I tested two).

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1812679)?

Comment: got the same issue, tried to run a getty console on tty7 and i see the same issue, strangely enough if i run login program on my local console it works...